# Previewing Website Prior To DNS Propogation

Tags: wordpress, hosting, nameservers

I'm doing marketing for a client.

I'm helping them move their WordPress site from one host to another (from ventraip to siteground). Their domain is also currently with ventraip. I've already set up hosting with siteground (haven't cancelled ventraip just yet).

The question being, is there a way to make adjustments and preview the website on siteground before pointing the nameservers/changing DNS? I've seen a few tutorials but they are for other hosting companies and there is nothing I can see in siteground's knowledge base.

If anyone knows a general format or a better way, would love to hear your input. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a nice solution would be to modify your local hosts file in order to preview your website using the current URL (which only on your machine will point to the new hsoting).

You can follow this guide by Kinsta, which works for every hosting: https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/edit-hosts-file/

This is what I do and I am pretty sure it works :)

Here is also a tutorial specific to SiteGround which uses a temporary url: https://iamnickdavis.com/temporary-url-siteground-migration/ but I never tested it.

Hope it helps, cheers!

Comment: francesco it did! thanks heaps for your help, really appreciate it :)